# PHP POST method Form Redirecting on action Page

Tags: php, html, forms, post, methods

I have created a simple HTML Form With Action on Different Website
After form data submission user is redirecting to action page but I want user stay on my website and form data go on another website..please help me

here is sample form

````
               <form class="form" action="https://api.promopmi.center/v1/sms/infobip" method="post">
               
                   <ul>
                       <li>
                           <input name="test1">
                       </li>
                       <li>
                           <textarea name="name112"></textarea>
                       </li>
                       
                       
                       <li>
                           <button type="submit" id="submit">Send SMS</button> <i id="result"></i>
                       </li>
                   
                       
                   </ul>
               </form>
           </div>```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `iframe`, and submit the data to that, using `target="iframeName"`, for example:

```
<iframe name="iframe1"></iframe>
<form class="form" action="https://api.promopmi.center/v1/sms/infobip" method="post" target="iframe1">
```

This way you will stay on the same page.

Comment: You can see more at https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_target.asp

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery and ajax $.post check my snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#sendmsg").click(function() {
    onfocusout: false;
    var mname = $("input").val();
    var msgct = $("textarea").val();
    if (mname.length > 0) {
      if (msgct.length > 0) {
        $.post("https://api.promopmi.center/v1/sms/infobip", {
            name: mname,
            message: msgct
          },
          function(data, status) {
            $("#result").text("Status:" + status);
          });
      } else {
        alert('message is empty');
      }
    } else {
      alert('name is empty');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form" action="javascrip:void(0)">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="text" name="name">
    </li>
    <li>
      <textarea name="message"></textarea>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button id="sendmsg" name="Send SMS">Send SMS</button>
      <i id="result"></i>
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways of doing it.
You can do by inserting the values in the database and then show it in that other page.
You can post the value to https://api.promopmi.center/v1/sms/infobip and create a redirect from that link to this as soon as the user opens the page.